# Function like Partial F-test but on unsupervised data in R

Tags: r

I want to test whether removing one variable will make any differences. However, there is no responding variable but only 4 independent variables in my data. Is there any function in r that can test for this?

Comment: Rather unclear and perhaps better asked on CV.com, but perhaps you seek clustering methods?

Comment: CV.com ? a website?

Comment: CrossValidated.com. It's part of the stackexchange.com system. It's for statistical methods and theory questions.